# Выдает ошибку mysql_connect в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Как подключиться к БД?

```
mysql_connect("localhost",'root') or die('<h1>Error to connect MySQL</h1>');
echo "<p>You connect MySQL</p>";
```

[image: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, oplorem ipsum, dolor sit amet,l ormem pidasoioiasdfosadufosau]

Comment: Извиняюсь, что не по теме. А что это за прекрасная тема для sublime text?

Comment: [здесь найдете](https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme)

Comment: благодарю покорно)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно залезть в документацию:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php

> **Внимание** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и
>   удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что у вас версия `php` как раз `7`.

Используем `mysqli_connect()`:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php